# Dynamic Element id in selenium @FindBy

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-java

Can someone throw some light on how to dynamically retrieve List of Id by PageSection.
Our Page Contains number of sections based on number of person information.each person is a Form based PageSection.

Here is an example.

```
@FindBy(css = "#personForm0 > fieldset > div.apisInfoRequired.statusBox.active > div.btn.action.addBtn > input")
public PageElement addInfantBtn;


@FindBy(css = "#personForm1 > fieldset > div.apisInfoRequired.statusBox.active > div.btn.action.addBtn > input")
public PageElement addAdultBtn;
```

`#personForm0` can be go upto `#personForm9`, now when i read that using `@FindBy`, I am facing difficulty with selenium. Can someone share your thought on how to write this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to find all elements that has a specific name or similar and the iterate over them and determine if you have found what are are searching for?

That is, instead of using

```
findElement(By.name("q"));
```

are you able to use

```
findElements(By.name("q"));
```

and iterate on the list of web elements that are returned?

An example of the html you are working with would probably give you a better answer.

Comment: i dont have a name on the element.
<input aria-required="true" value="" id="pax-0-field-pn-doc-passport" type="text" class="m" aria-invalid="true">

Comment: Then use CSS or XPATH to locate them. They are also possible ti use with findElements()

Comment: Thomas, these are different form on html, based on the number of items(Person), e.g. how do dynamically use @FindBy(css = "id1"), css = id2,id3,id4, Because each has has separate multiple elements with indexed values. pfa 2 classes i am using.